# Ejecutar funcion de javascript antes de ejecutar una funcion de servidor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Tengo una pagina web en C# ASP  que al pulsar un boton me pasa a otra pagina llamando a un metodo del servidor con onServerClick.
Necesito que antes de ejecutar el metodo del servidor ejecute un javascript de la pagina o que no refresque la pantalla cuando ejecute el metodo del servidor onServerClick ( Estilo ajax )

Comment: si no pones codigo ejemplo, prueba esto a ver si te sirve https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57937-onclick-vs-onserverclick/

Comment: Es algo asi lo que quiero pero necesito que primero se ejecute el proceso de la funcion en Javascript y cuando termine este proceso llame al metodo del onserverclick.

Answer (score 1):

Si el botón es un asp:button, tienes que usar los eventos OnClientClick para el código Javascript, y el OnClick para el código de servidor.

`<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Botón Button" OnClick="boton_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:BotonPulsado();" />`

Si el botón es un input type="button", los eventos son OnClick para el Javascript, y OnServerClick para el código de servidor.

`<input type="button" id="btnInput" value="Botón Input" runat="server" onserverclick="boton_Click" onclick="javascript:BotonPulsado();" />`

Comment: Funciona pero necesito que primero se ejecute la parte de JavaScript y cuando termine ejecute la parte del servidor

Comment: ¿Y no lo hace así? A lo mejor debes sustituir "javascript:BotonPulsado();" por "return javascript:BotonPulsado();", y dentro de BotonPulsado devolver true si ha ido bien y quieres que continúe (al servidor), o false si quieres que pare.

Comment: No funciona porque la función de JavaScript es asíncrona.